# Circular Import error in Django occurs only when i import geemap package

Tags: django, import, geemap

I am trying to use geemap in combination with django to build a web app for plotting satellite data. I have installed the geemap package in my django project. My projects name is CustomMaps, and the directory structure is as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjL5T.png)

The code for my CustomMaps.urls.py
is as below

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url




urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('plotmap/', include('PlotMap.urls')),
]
```

The code for my PlotMap.urls.py is as follows

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from .views import hello



urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', hello, name = 'hello'),
]
```

And my PlotMap.views.py is as follows

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
import geemap as gm
#import pandas as pd

def hello(request):
   map = gm.Map()
   return render(request, "PlotMap/hello.html", { "m" : map})
```

But I am getting the following error on running the project

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Internship\Django App\MyProject\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", 
line 604, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Internship\Django App\MyProject\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Internship\Django App\MyProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "D:\Internship\Django App\MyProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 423, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "D:\Internship\Django App\MyProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "D:\Internship\Django App\MyProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "D:\Internship\Django App\MyProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "D:\Internship\Django App\MyProject\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", 
line 416, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "D:\Internship\Django App\MyProject\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\Internship\Django App\MyProject\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", 
line 611, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'CustomMaps.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

But if I run same code after changing my views.py like below it works perfectly fine.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
#import geemap as gm
#import pandas as pd

def hello(request):
   #map = gm.Map()
   return render(request, "PlotMap/hello.html", { })
```

I am not able to understand why is my 'import geemap' leading to circular import error in CustomMaps.urls.py. I tried searching for the same, but have not been able to find anything till now. If someone can please help me out then i will be able to proceed with my work soon, Thank You.

Comment: Try to replace a `map` with `g_map`. `map` is a reserved keyword in Python.

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak I tried replacing 'map' with 'g_map' according to your advice, but it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I tried installing a new version of python(3.8) and also downloaded a new version of geemap(0.11.4) which solved the issue.

But, I am still struggling on how to display the instance of `geemap.Map()` in my django template, any suggestions would be much helpful.

I will post a new question for the same.
Here: [How to display an instance of geemap.Map() in Django Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71233305/how-to-display-an-instance-of-geemap-map-in-django-template)